# Working with filezilla on linux server as local site in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, filezilla

I am trying to connect my local linuxserver as a Local Site URL as \linuxserver\www

In brief, i am using ubuntu as a local server and client as well clients need to upload file from local client to server in that case

We are plan to use filezilla but in that local server cannot be connected I don't no why is there is any way to upload local file to server.

I have tried following in the local site url

> \linuxserver
>
> \194.XXX.XXX.XXX

Explain me if there is any way with my ubuntu server where filezilla has installed.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your local site is the client machine on which you launched filezilla. You simply write there the directory from/to which you want to upload files. (or just browse to that directory) e.g: /www/data

Your remote site is where the FTP-server is. Just write the FTP-servers IP-address in the **Host** field, and if necessary fill in the Username/Password/Port fields also. Then press Quickconnect.

If your FTP-server and client is on the same machine then just write `localhost` in the **host** field. This is what you need?